# What is wrong with my FastAPI Reverse Proxy?

Tags: nginx, proxy, fastapi

I have a web application which is setup in the following way: the frontend is being served by nginx. The backend is handled by FastAPI. I setup a rule in nginx to proxy all requests with url `/api` to the backend directly. Now, I also proxy to Grafana. The way I did this was to build a reverse proxy within my FastAPI server. So in nginx, I have a rule to proxy all requests with url `/grafana` to FastAPI. FastAPI then does some user authentication before proxying to the grafana server. The exception is that any Grafana websocket connection gets proxied directly from nginx to the grafana server.

Here's my nginx conf file

```
server {
    
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    
    root /var/www/web-app/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }

    # grafana reverse proxy
    location /grafana {
        proxy_set_header Origin http://localhost:3000;
        # proxy_set_header Origin https://example.com;
        proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }

    location /grafana/api/live {
        rewrite  ^/(.*)  /$1 break;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3030;
    }
    
    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Here's my FastAPI proxy

```py
async def _reverse_proxy(request: Request):
    url = httpx.URL(path=request.url.path,
                    query=request.url.query.encode("utf-8"))
    new_header = MutableHeaders(request.headers)
    if "grafana_session" not in request.cookies:
        if "authorization" not in request.headers:
            return RedirectResponse("/")
        jwt_token = request.headers["authorization"].replace('Bearer ', '')
        # user authentication stuff...
        current_user = get_current_user_from_token(token=jwt_token, db=some_session)
        org = get_org_by_id(current_user.org_id, some_session)
        if org is None:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=404,
                detail="Organization not found",
            )
        del new_header['authorization']
        new_header['X-WEBAUTH-USER'] = current_user.username
        new_header['X-Grafana-Org-Id'] = f"{org.grafana_org_id}"
    if "authorization" in new_header:
        del new_header['authorization']
    rp_req = client.build_request(request.method, url,
                                  headers=new_header.raw,
                                  content=await request.body())
    rp_resp = await client.send(rp_req, stream=True)
    return StreamingResponse(
        rp_resp.aiter_raw(),
        status_code=rp_resp.status_code,
        headers=rp_resp.headers,
        background=BackgroundTask(rp_resp.aclose),
    )

app = FastAPI(title=settings.PROJECT_NAME, version=settings.PROJECT_VERSION)
origins = ["http://localhost:3000", "https://example.com"]
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
app.include_router(api_router, prefix=settings.API_V1_STR)
app.add_route("/grafana/{path:path}", _reverse_proxy, ["GET", "POST", "DELETE"])
```

If I run this locally on `localhost:3000` (with some modifications to nginx to be listening on 3000 instead of 443 ssl), everything works perfectly. If I try in production at `example.com`, I have to include this hacky bit `proxy_set_header Origin http://localhost:3000;` to change the origin in a request to my FastAPI proxy to make it work. Why is this happening?

**NOTE:** I've checked the grafana server logs to make sure that it wasn't the issue. None of the requests make it past the FastAPI server, it is the one returning error 403, origin not allowed.